# Feign without class mapping

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, feign

I got json as below, how can I get item price without creating model classes with Feign in Spring Boot? When I create classes it works, but I want to avoid creating a lot of classes to get only one field.

```
    "item": {
        "country": {
            "company": {
                "department": {
                    "product": {
                        "name": "name"
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Return a `String` or `Map` then extract it.

Comment: As a side note: who designed your API? It doesn't look very client-friendly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/octomix/josson
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.octomix.josson/josson

```
implementation 'com.octomix.josson:josson:1.3.20'

-------------------------------------------------

Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
        "{\n" +
        "    \"item\": {\n" +
        "        \"country\": {\n" +
        "            \"company\": {\n" +
        "                \"department\": {\n" +
        "                    \"product\": {\n" +
        "                        \"name\": \"name\",\n" +
        "                        \"price\": \"123.4\"\n" +
        "                    }\n" +
        "                }\n" +
        "            }\n" +
        "        } \n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}");
// getNode() returns a Jackson JsonNode
System.out.println(josson.getNode("item.country.company.department.product.price")); // -> 123.4
```